cJSON_Duplicate doesn't appear to work correctly
I want to create a JSON string containing multiple list entries (In reality they are populated in a timer ISR, the below runable example however simuulates the addition with a for loop). For some reason however, I do not get the resulting JSON string after calling cJSON_Duplicate() and cJSON_Print() and I'm wondering why not and how I can fix this.
My example (json_simulate() below):
void add_list_entry(cJSON *parent, int index, uint32_t x, uint32_t z, uint32_t t_h, uint64_t t_us) {
    // Create the object representing the list item
    cJSON *entry = cJSON_CreateObject();
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(entry, "X", x);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(entry, "Z", z);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(entry, "t_h", t_h);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(entry, "t_us", (double)t_us);

    // Create an array to hold the single item
    cJSON *array = cJSON_CreateArray();
    cJSON_AddItemToArray(array, entry);

    // Add the array to the parent object, using the incrementing index as a string key
    char key[11];  // enough to hold an integer up to 4 billion
    snprintf(key, sizeof(key), "%d", index);
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(parent, key, array);
}

void json_simulate(void)
{
    cJSON *root = cJSON_CreateObject();  // Root should be an object
    char *json_output;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        add_list_entry(root,       // root json handle
                       i,           // element counter for each item
                       TIM1->CNT,   // X encoder input
                       m_curr.dist, // Z distance
                       m_curr.t_h,  // time in seconds
                       TIM5->CNT);  // us timer
    }
    taskENTER_CRITICAL();
    if (m_jsonroot != NULL) {
        cJSON_Delete(m_jsonroot);  // Ensure to delete previous data if any
    }
    m_jsonroot = cJSON_Duplicate(root, 1); // copy to global json handle
    m_tx_msg = 1;                  // set global update flag
    json_output = cJSON_Print(m_jsonroot);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
    free(json_output);             // free the result of cJSON_Print()
    cJSON_Delete(root);            // Delete the local root object
}

add_list_entry() is invoked in a critical section from my timer ISR, too (not visible in above simulation).
I'm wondering why this is not working as expected?

Where is cJSON_Duplicate() documented? I don't see it at https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON?tab=readme-ov-file#table-of-contents

Why do you need to duplicate it? Why not just do m_jsonroot = root;?

@Barmar https://docs.freeswitch.org/switch__json_8h.html#a9acb1410be711f33d7c6d39f916b2d35 :(

That doesn't seem to be documentation. It looks more like cross-referenced source code. It never describes what the functions do.

I found the bottom comment here seemingly from the original author: of cJSON: https://sourceforge.net/p/cjson/discussion/998969/thread/ebecf663/

In any case, can you be more specific about what's going wrong? What are you expecting, what are you getting instead?

Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Is it possible there's something wrong with root? Sprinkle some cJSON_Print(root) around to make sure root is ok.

Your JSON structure seems odd. An object with numeric keys and single element arrays as objects? {"0": [{"X": 1, "Z": 2, "t_h": 3, "t_us": 4}], "1": [{"X": 1, "Z": 2, "t_h": 3, "t_us": 4}], ...} It would seem simpler to use an array of objects. [ {"X": 1, "Z": 2, "t_h": 3, "t_us": 4}, {"X": 1, "Z": 2, "t_h": 3, "t_us": 4} ]

What are you expecting to get? What are you getting instead?

@Shawn I expect my final json string to be in json_output  but instead I only get \0 in it
